# Как сохранить файлы в master, но удалить их в другой ветке?

Tags: git

Есть проект, который нужно разделить на 2 "относительно" независимые версии. В новой версии нужно исключить некоторые из файлов, которые должны остаться в старой. В ходе развития новой версии, в ней будут создаваться и изменяться файлы, которые будут актуальные и для старой.
Проблема в том, что если влить изменения новой в старую, то помимо полезного добавления/изменения файлов, в ней удаляются те самые исключенные, которые должны там находиться.

Comment: `git checkout старая-версия && git merge -s ours master`

Comment: @PetSerAI, это стратегии разрешения конфликтов, если я правильно понимаю, поэтому в данном случае не очень поможет.

Comment: Храните общие файлы либо вообще не в Git, либо в отдельном репозитории.

Comment: @0andriy, Как-то это не впечатляет... должен же быть способ! Я только начал использовать git, и уже такой недостаток...

Comment: Это недостаток в понимании как работают системы контроля версий, и как правильно разделять большой проект на составляющие.

Comment: @0andriy, а почему бы не поделиться знанием? просто погуглив я ответ на нахожу...

Comment: Я не могу поделиться тем, о чём не знаю деталей, а именно суть вашего проекта и т.п. И время, потраченное на такую работу, уже будет требовать соответствующей компенсации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В зависимости от масштаба удалений и вливаемых обратно изменений я использую одну из двух стратегий:

1. Делаю `merge` с `--no-commit` и вручную откатываю удаления.
2. Делаю интерактивный `rebase` из новой ветки только коммитов изменений (без коммита удаления) из новой ветки в master. Иногда по старой привычке делаю не `rebase`, а формирую патчи для отдельных коммитов и вручную накатываю их на master.

Но чаще стараюсь, чтобы в новой ветке изменения не вносились. Делаю их в master и мержу в нее.